# SIP vs RTSP . Which one should be used for video sessions

Tags: sip, rtsp

For a server which tries implement video chatting or (multimedia or text chatting for that matter) using RTP which one should be used for control? SIP or RTSP? I went through the abstract of the corresponding RFCs however I could only see that both of them are used for just controls and the actual transmission of data is done using other protocols like UDP or RTP over UDP. From my understanding, SIP is for controlling transmission of data where sessions between two users are involved and RTSP otherwise. Of course it is a very basic understanding. What are the actual differences between these 2 protocols ? A simple google search did not give me a comparison.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Both SIP and RTSP are signalling protocols. SIP can handle more diverse and sophisticated scenarios than RTSP and I can't think of anything significant that RTSP can do that SIP can't. The advantage of RTSP over SIP is that it's a lot simpler to use and implement.

RTSP is suited for client-server applications, for example where one server has a media stream to feed to multiple clients. SIP is suited for peer-to-peer scenarios where media streams need to flow both ways.

One way to think of it is that RTSP is kind of like using the television where the broadcaster is the server and your tv is the client; you turn your tv on and can switch between a certain number of pre-defined channels. SIP is like using the phone (not surprising given it was mainly designed for VoIP), you can call anyone you want or they can call you.

Both SIP and RTSP use exactly the same media transfer mechanisms such as SDP and RTP so they aren't a consideration when choosing between them.